# PhpStorm and Touch Bar

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, macbookpro-touch-bar

When you use PhpStorm on mac with touch bar, you can define custom buttons based on context or used modifier key (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>, <kbd>Option</kbd> etc.). But on swapping touch bar buttons, ie. with <kbd>Cmd</kbd> key, there is a little delay and fade animation before new buttons shows up.

Is there possibility to make that new buttons shows immediately?

Answer (score 1):

In fact, there is one big cumulative YouTrack request about TouchBar support:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-163208

However, to be honest, there are no related tickets or comments about animation speed and its tweaking. Please try to install the latest EAP version (https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/eap/) and if it does not help, submit a ticket at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA or leave a comment in the thread mentioned above. It would be also fantastic if you could attach a video record there to illustrate the issue.